# How to get the bytesIn/bytesOut on a request basis using Jetty Client

Tags: java, http, jetty, http2, jetty-9

I am using Jetty Client 11 and would like to compute for each request the sent/received bytes.

I am using High Level HttpClient .
I have read this documentation but I don't see any information on how to do that:

- https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/jetty-11/programming-guide/index.html

I see there is a way to have this information by doing:

```
        ConnectionStatistics connectionStatistics = new ConnectionStatistics();
        httpClient.addBean(connectionStatistics);
```

Then:

```
        Request request = httpClient.newRequest(uri)
                .version(HttpVersion.HTTP_2)
                .timeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT_SECONDS, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        request.send(listener);
        ConnectionStatistics connectionStatistics = httpClient.getBean(ConnectionStatistics.class);
        System.out.println(connectionStatistics.getSentBytes()+"/"+ connectionStatistics.getReceivedBytes());
```

And I must be doing something wrong as it does not even work on a global basis, it always gives 0.

And anyway, I don't see how to make it work on a request basis.

**EDIT:**

I tried @sbordet answer:

```
httpClient.newRequest(...)
  .onRequestContent((req, buf) -> requestBytes.add(buf.remaining()))
  ...
  .onResponseContent((res, buf) -> responseBytes.add(buf.remaining()))
  ...
  send(...);
```

and it works fine for response.
**BUT** for request, I would like to measure the bytes sent, it always give 0 (Note I only have gets without Content) while I would expect to have the raw size (the Raw HTTP request bytes including header size ...)

Answer (score 5):

You can count request bytes using `Request.ContentListener` and response bytes using `Response.ContentListener`:

```java
httpClient.newRequest(...)
  .onRequestContent((req, buf) -> requestBytes.add(buf.remaining()))
  ...
  .onResponseContent((res, buf) -> responseBytes.add(buf.remaining()))
  ...
  send(...);
```

Comment: Thanks, if the response is gzipped, is it before or after decompression ?

Comment: It works fine for response, but for request, I would like to measure the bytes sent, it always give 0 (Note I only have gets without Content) while I would expect to have the raw size

Comment: Hello @sbordet, I updated my question with my comment, it would be nice if you could have a look. Thanks